# JavaScript document.domain Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, dom, same-origin-policy

While I was testing the SOP, i came to this scenario two documents has a relationship with the same domain as i would expected and it throws an error when i try to get the location.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Open https://www.google.com
2. from the console `let opened = window.open("https://www.google.com")`
3. from the same window do `opened.location.toString()` which will return the correct location
4. from the second tab's console do `document.domain = "www.google.com"`
5. from the first tab do `opened.location.toString()` and you will get an error

   ```
   Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
   at <anonymous>:1:12
   ```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is not a bug. The same-origin policy is a security mechanism that ensures that window objects only have access to the informations they are authorized to get. In your case, this includes having access to `opened.location`.

Upon creation, both tabs have the same origin, which allows the first one to access `opened.location`. But after the call to `document.domain='www.google.com'`, they don't anymore.

*"What? But in both tabs, `window.location.origin` are identical"*

Yes, but it is a little bit more complex. The origin is defined by the scheme/host/port tuple, see @TheUnknown's answer for more details. The scheme and host stay the same all along, and they're the one included in the string of `window.location.origin`.

**The tricky thing to know is that any call to `document.domain`, including `document.domain = document.domain`, causes the port number to be overwritten with `null`**, therefore causing a difference in the two tabs' origins, and preventing them from communicating informations like `opened.location` with one another, thus the error.

<sub>Informations extracted from MDN's [guide on same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)</sub>

Comment: In both instances, the port is null - both before and after setting it. The port is only set if it is explicitly in the domain

Comment: I beg to differ. Running `document.domain = document.domain` in *both* tabs allows the first one to still access `opened`'s fields

Comment: From your own link, *"Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified)"*

Comment: Port is not specified in either place, so the restriction does not apply

Comment: The linked MDN *specifically* precises how and why setting `domain.domain` can result in permissions errors. It also explains that *The port number is checked separately by the browser*, which might explains this behavior.

Comment: `typeof window.location.port` does not change before or after either

Comment: a great way to test your theory would be to try and replicate the issue on IE - if it is the port, IE shouldn't have the issue since it doesn't do a port check

Comment: *The port number is checked separately by the browser* might point to the direction that the same-origin checking cannot be replicated by the value in `window.location.port`

Comment: _Port
IE doesn't include port into same-origin checks._

Comment: Give it a try in IE, I would but I'm on the train. It would confirm your theory

Comment: is there a way to specify the port? I tried location.port in both windows and they are empty.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would recommend, you read [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

> The same-origin policy is a critical security mechanism that restricts
>   how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a
>   resource from another origin. It helps isolate potentially malicious
>   documents, reducing possible attack vectors.
>
> Two URLs have the same origin if the **protocol**, port (if specified), and host are the same for both. You may see this referenced as the "scheme/host/port tuple", or just "tuple". (A "tuple" is a set of items that together comprise a whole — a generic form for double/triple/quadruple/quintuple/etc.)

In this particular case, you open a window with ***HTTPS*** protocol, however when you set the domain, the protocol is changed to ***HTTP***, see image below:

[image: protocol has changed]

As per [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), if the protocols are not the same, then its a violation of the principle and hence you get the error

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.google.com" from accessing a **cross-origin** frame.

*cross-origin* is the keyword here.

Also, check out this [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/2196341) for more details.

Comment: Mmmh, not convinced. Your answer was sure a good input, but the same error can be observed when using http://example.com instead of https://google.com

Comment: @NinoFiliu can you elaborate? yes, it wont work since both are different domain.

Comment: The hover over is the same before and after the `document.location` change; they are both `http://www.google.com`

Comment: @TheUknown if you replace *every* `https://www.google.com` by `http://example.com` in the OP's question, the error still shows

Comment: Got it. I didnt test that part.'d have to do some more research into this.

Comment: I already found an answer, which I'm currently redacting! just FYI

Comment: Done! I mentionned you in my comments so as not to duplicate explanations about what is an origin and how can they differ from one another

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit uninformative (just states facts), nevertheless:

- After you change `domain` in window B, window B stops accounting window A as `opener`.
- Since window A is no longer considered an opener of window B, the access is prohibited.

This makes me think, that altering `document.domain` is considered potentially insecure and is "punished" by orphaning the child window.