# How can I have the reCAPTCHA work when using FirebaseUI auth component?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, recaptcha, firebaseui

I'm creating a web app using Polymer to build the front-end, and I'm using FirebaseUI component as a drop-in to support Firebase Phone Authentication, but immediately the page renders that has the FirebaseUI component on it I'm getting this error in my console logs: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` And after that the `reCAPTCHA` won't be solved. I want to use firebase phone authentication in the [app](https://safepay-6b798.firebaseapp.com/signin) I'm building.

I tried running the app both on my local dev server serving it on `http` but still behaving just the same even when I run on firebase (`https`). I tried to open an [issue on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/590) but still no helpful response was gotten.

Below is the code that's in charge of configuring and specifying the location where the FirebaseUI phone auth component should be rendered.

```
ready() {
        super.ready();
        // FirebaseUI config.
        var uiConfig = {
            signInSuccessUrl: `${window.location.origin}/seller-dashboard`,
            signInOptions: [
                {
                    provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                    recaptchaParameters: {
                        type: 'image', // 'audio'
                        size: 'normal', // 'invisible' or 'compact'
                        badge: 'bottomleft' //' bottomright' or 'inline' applies to invisible.
                    },
                    defaultCountry: '+260'
                }
            ],
            // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
            // function.
            // Terms of service url/callback.
            tosUrl: `${window.location.origin}/terms`,
            // Privacy policy url/callback.
            privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
                window.location.assign(`${window.location.origin}/privacy`);
            }
        };

        // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
        var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
        // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
        ui.start(this.$.container, uiConfig);
    }
```

When the `page` where the `firebaseui phone authentication` component is is rendered I'm having these `console logs` on Google Chrome: 

`XHR finished loading: GET "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getRecaptchaParam?key=AIzaSyAUb_eFUs_zNJ5HMtlRV3Ghg1JLQ63enL4&cb=1558695304328".
recaptcha__en.js:529`

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at wG.K.l9 (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__en.js:529:183)
    at yu (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__en.js:532:11)
    at Object.init (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__en.js:542:72)
    at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=v1558333958099&k=6LcMZR0UAAAAALgPMcgHwga7gY5p8QMg1Hj-bmUv&cb=2zr5gn9cy630:184:30`

I'm running everything on `macOS Mojave`, browser: `Google Chrome 74.0.3729.157`, Firebase UI version: `6.0.2`, and Polymer 3.

Any help how I can have this work?

Comment: Check this link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879607/javascript-document-domain-uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin/55425041

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem and verification should work regardless; Firebase's demo shows the same error.I had the exact same issue, but after hours of attempts realised I made the silly mistake of adding my mobile number in the console as a number for testing. FB won't send you a code in this case, and you will have to specify the verification you specified in the console.