# How do i get all images from a iframe

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, iframe

I want to get all images from a iframe and turn it into a array to get it src

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

var images = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("img").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("inv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inv").innerHTML + "<br>"+ images[0].src;
```

`error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at update (file:///H:/images.html:56:63)`

`error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at update (http://localhost/images.html:56:63)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame). Also see [JavaScript document.domain Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879607/javascript-document-domain-uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin).

Comment: also tried with xamp

Comment: As an aside, please review what the `getElementsByTagName` method returns, and check if image elements can have `innerHTML`  content. (hint: they don't take closing tags).